# One to Many Association Object Will Not Save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I set up a has_many belongs_to relationship in my two models and followed Ryan Bates' screencast on how to set up the controller. When I submit my form to create the new object, the nested object does not save for some reason. Here are my models:

```
class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bids, dependent: :destroy
end

class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :auction
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :auction_id, presence: true
end
```

and my nested object controller:

```
  class BidsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
    @bids = @auction.bids
  end

  def new
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
    @bid = @auction.bids.build
  end

  def create
     @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
    @bid = @auction.bids.create(params[:bid])
    @bid.save
    if @bid.save
      flash[:success] = "Bid has been successfully placed."
    else
      @bid.errors
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
     @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
     @bid = @auction.bids.find
    @bid.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed Bid."
    redirect_to auction_url(@bid.article_id)
  end
end
```

my form:

```
<h1>Create a New Bid</h1>
<%= form_for ([@auction, @bid]) do |f|%>
<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<%end%>
```

and my terminal output:

```
Started POST "/auctions/1/bids" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-30 17:59:13 -0600
Processing by BidsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"dkZBcab1rgZjtJGF3LAJ//exK6liglZ0Fy4mg7HWEt0=", "commit"=>"Create Bid", "auction_id"=>"1"}
  Auction Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "auctions".* FROM "auctions"  WHERE "auctions"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bid object needs a `user_id` because you have `validates :user_id, presence: true` in the class definition.

When you call `@bid.save` in the controller, however, `@bid` does not have a `user_id` value, therefore the transaction gets rolled back because of the failing validation.

You should be able to see this by looking at `@bid.errors.full_messages` in the create action, after you've called `@bid.save`. (Look up the pry gem if you're not already familiar with it...it would be a perfect tool to let you do this inspection.)

Try replacing your create action with this:

```
def create
  @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
  @bid = @auction.bids.new params[:bid].merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  if @bid.save
    flash[:success] = "Bid has been successfully placed."
  else
    flash[:error] = @bid.errors.full_messages.join('. ')
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

This assumes that you have access to the current user in the controller as `current_user`. Devise and other popular auth solutions supply this, or you can do so yourself.

Note also that your original code tries to write `@bid` to the database 3 separate times, which is twice more than you need to. Here are the offending lines:

```
def create 
  ...
  @bid = @auction.bids.create(params[:bid])
  @bid.save
  if @bid.save
  ...
```

`#create` instantiates an object and attempts to write it to the database. In my code above, I've replaced `@auction.bids.create(params...)` with `@auction.bids.new(params...)`. This initializes `@bid` without trying to persist it to the db.

I also removed the first `@bid.save` because the line below it `if @bid.save` will accomplish the same thing.

Finally, your line `@bid.errors` doesn't do anything useful. I modified it to store the error messages in your flash hash, which you can then use in your view to display the errors to the user.

Comment: Excellent response, John. Thanks for your help! Yes, I do see that writing those extra times to the database is not necessary. Thank you for pointing that out.